# fade in fade out animation on three different text css

Tags: html, css

I would like to use this CSS fade in and fade out code in three different texts but it only works only with two different texts.

HTML:

```
<h1 class="nametag"> text 1 </h1>
<h1 class="nametag"> text 2 </h1>
<h1 class="nametag"> text 3 </h1>
```

**CSS**

```
.nametag{
  position: absolute;
}

.nametag:nth-child(1){
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;  
}

.nametag:nth-child(2){
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes fade{
    0%,45% {
      opacity: 0;
}
    100%{
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain in further detail what you are looking for. Do you want them to fade in and out on hover? On click? On scroll?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is that the text is always shown. When you run the animation once with a certain delay it partially works.

I have added a delay and another keyframe to hide the text again.

```css
.nametag{
  position: absolute;
}

.nametag:nth-of-type(1){
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

.nametag:nth-of-type(2){
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

.nametag:nth-of-type(3){
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 8s;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes fade{
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    60% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<h1 class="nametag"> text 1 </h1>
<h1 class="nametag"> text 2 </h1>
<h1 class="nametag"> text 3 </h1>
```

You could use a fixed text and just animate the number.

Read more about [animations on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You have put the css code for animating them in `.nametag:nth-child(1)` and `.nametag:nth-child(2)`. That is why it only works for the first 2 and not the third `.nametag`.